# Automate account creation by joining mailing list?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

I'm using Wordpress/WooCommerce where users can join the mailing list in MailChimp. But is there a way to also automate account creation after they join the mailing list and generate a temporary password to be sent via email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Look into MailChimp [webhooks](http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/how-to-set-up-webhooks).

Basic flow would be:
1. User subscribes
2. MC sends post request to specified callback URL (you can make a page with custom template for example. Easiest way)  upon subscription
3. Your page at specified callback URL accepts JSON sent by MC
4. Create new account
5. Send generated password to email

Optionally, you can also set up unsubscribe webhook and remove account when that happens.